# R Vegan: evaluate pairwise permanova significance between comparisons

Tags: r, vegan, pairwise, mds

I'm looking for a statistical test that will allow me to evaluate whether pairwise comparisons are statistically different from one another. I'm using ecological community count (abundance) data sampled across multiple sites before, during, and after an environmental perturbation inside and outside of treatment plots. I'm specifically interested in:

1. whether *treatment* before vs. during and/or *treatment* before vs. after is significant, AND the same for control.
2. Importantly, whether the pairwise comparisons above are statistically different.

The first task is straightforward and easy to acquire using `pairwise.adonis2()`. However, I am not sure how to approach the second task. I'd specifically like to evaluate:

- whether *Treatment before vs. during* is significantly different from C*ontrol before vs. during*, and likewise...
- whether *Treatment before vs. after* is different from *Control before vs. after*.

I've modified `dune` to fit my treatment (control, treatment) and period (before, during, after) levels simply for illustrative purposes. Is there a way to statistically evaluate these pairwise comparisons?

```
require(vegan)
require(pairwiseAdonis)
require(dplyr)

# Species and environmental data
dune <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.spe.txt', row.names = 1)

dune.env <- read.delim ('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zdealveindy/anadat-r/master/data/dune2.env.txt', row.names = 1)

#rename 
dune.env$Use <- recode_factor(dune.env$Use, "Haypastu" = "before")
dune.env$Use <- recode_factor(dune.env$Use, "Hayfield" = "during")
dune.env$Use <- recode_factor(dune.env$Use, "Pasture" = "after")

dune.env$Management <- recode_factor(dune.env$Management, "HF" = "SF")
dune.env$Management <- recode_factor(dune.env$Management, "NM" = "BF")
dune.env$Management <- recode_factor(dune.env$Management, "SF" = "Control")
dune.env$Management <- recode_factor(dune.env$Management, "BF" = "Treatment")

#define pairwise comparisons

dune.env1 <- dune.env %>% mutate(contrast = paste(Management, Use))

#create distmat
dune_distmat <- vegdist(dune, method="bray")

#pairwise permanova
pair_perm <- pairwise.adonis2(dune_distmat ~ contrast, 
                                    data = dune.env1, permutations = 999)
```